# Flowplayer playlist only plays first clip

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, playlist

I have a `flowplayer` setup to play multiple clips/videos. However, the situation is that it is not performing the way I intend for it to perform. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to make the second and/or subsequent videos automatically play once the first clip has ended. Any ideas?

```
$f("player", "/flowplayer/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.11.swf", {
key: '#$*******************',
logo: {
    url: 'logo.png',
    fullscreenOnly: false,
    displayTime: 11,
    top: 195,
    left:  400.25,
    fadeSpeed: 1100,
    opacity: 0,
    linkUrl: 'http://www.mysite.com',
    linkWindow: '_blank'

},

clip: {
    autoPlay: true,
    autoBuffering: true,

    onCuepoint: [[00,5000,13000,30000,39000,47000,53000,67000,75000,86000,100000,110000,118000], function(clip, point) {
        info.innerHTML = '<iframe src="cue_player.php?id=3716&time='+ point+'" height="490" width="730" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'
    }],

    // track start event for this clip
    onStart: function(clip) {
        _tracker._trackEvent("Videos", "Play", "");
    },

    // track pause event for this clip. time (in seconds) is also tracked
    onPause: function(clip) {
        _tracker._trackEvent("Videos", "Pause", "", parseInt(this.getTime()));
    },

    // track stop event for this clip. time is also tracked
    onStop: function(clip) {
        _tracker._trackEvent("Videos", "Stop", "", parseInt(this.getTime()));
    },

    // track finish event for this clip
    onFinish: function(clip) {
        _tracker._trackEvent("Videos", "Finish", "");
    },

    provider: 'rtmp'
}, 
playlist:[      {                 
        url: 'first_clip.mp4', 
        start: '0'
        },
        {
            url:'second_clip.mp4',
        }],  

    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
            url: '/flowplayer/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.10.swf',
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://video.mysite.com/videostream'
        }
    }
}
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. This is how I had it:

```
playlist:[{                 
    url: 'first_clip.mp4', 
    start: '0'
    },
    {
        url:'second_clip.mp4', //does removing this comma help?
    }],
```

But the solution was to place an "/mp4:" directly before the file name. So now it looks like this and works:

```
playlist:[{                 
    url: 'mp4:first_clip.mp4', 
    start: '0'
    },
    {
        url:'mp4:second_clip.mp4', //does removing this comma help?
    }],
```

Not sure if it makes a difference or not, but I am using a video server instead of a web server to serve up the video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems as though the hanging comma in the second object may cause an error which might prevent what you are wanting:

```
playlist:[      {                 
        url: 'first_clip.mp4', 
        start: '0'
        },
        {
            url:'second_clip.mp4', //does removing this comma help?
        }],
```

Comment: Actually that's required in order to separate the playlist section from the plugins section. Removing that comma makes the entire script crash.